# Are these errors related, and are they problems with hard or software?

Tags: windows-7, error-logging

I've had some problems with random BSODs on booting the last couple of days, and i desided to check the error log for problems. I am seeing a massive ammount of errors, and i'd like to know whether they are related, and whether they are hard- or software problems.

After booting windows explorer repeatedly crashes on starting, but once it actually works everything keeps running fine.

```
Service control manager; error code: 2140993535
```

This error occurs at least every minute.

```
PNRPSvc; error code: 0x80630801
```

Slightly less often then the previous one, but still very often.

```
Application error; Dwm.exe; error code: 0xc0000005; Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\atidxx64.dll
```

A couple of times after booting, possibly related to the windows explorer problem?

```
Kernel power
```

After i manage to succesfully boot.

I am positive there is no power failure when these errors occurs. And since the system keeps working fine once it has been booted, I wouldn't suspect the power supply to be the problem.

I was planning to reinstall Windows (7) next week anyway, but i'd like to be sure this is not a hardware related problem.

Could anyone provide some insights?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run chkdsk /f on the C partition, once done, run a sfc /scannow from a command prompt, see if it finds any corrupt system files and replaces them.

Once that is done scan for malware, [see my post over here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533)

Answer (score 0):

Well those error codes are unusual and possibly incorrect/corrupt. Looking at the errors in question, it looks like your network (wireless?) and video adapter drivers are conflicting. Your best bet is to try to update your network adapter’s driver to the latest version, though your video adapter is more likely to have a [newer version](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx).